# How can I find out the repeating node labels in a path in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a path that contains several labels like Shipped, Received, Ready to ship node labels. I want to know if a certain path has multiple occurrences of node labels. They may not be in order.

```
(Shipped)-[:NEXT]->()-[:NEXT]->()-[:NEXT]-(:ReadyToShip)-[:NEXT]-()-[:NEXT]-(:ReadyToShip)-[:NEXT]-(:Received)
```

i have many paths but I want to find all the paths which have 2  or more occurrences of the ReadyToShip node labels like the one above. How can I do this? I can extract all the possible path between 2 types of nodes using this :

```
match path=(s:Shipped)-[:NEXT*]->(m:Received) return distinct extract(p in nodes(path) | labels(p))
```

But I have to extract it out and filter these myself. How can I do this in Cypher?

Comment: Do you have APOC Procedures installed, or capable of being installed? There are some features for finding multiple occurrences of values within collections that can be helpful here.

Comment: @InverseFalcon : Yes I do have apoc procedures installed.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I tried the apoc.coll.occurrences and I managed to get some results. Would you know if I can use multiple values as the 2nd argument?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. You may want to look at `apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount()`, and filter down to only interested values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This query should return every path that has *at least* 2 `ReadyToShip` nodes, and the number of `ReadyToShip` nodes in that path:

```
MATCH p=(s:Shipped)-[:NEXT*]->(:ReadyToShip)-[:NEXT*]->(:ReadyToShip)-[:NEXT*]->(m:Received)
RETURN
  p,
  REDUCE(s = 0, n IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN 'ReadyToShip' IN LABELS(n) THEN s + 1 ELSE s END) AS num;
```

Comment: Yup I was using a similar query but what about the cases where I don't know how many times the ReadyToShip node repeats?

Comment: The query should find all paths that have *at least* 2 `ReadyToShip` nodes.

Comment: That helps. Is there a way to count the number of ReadyToShip nodes as well ? For eg 2 nodes in path 1 as compared to 3 in path 2.